# putting two operands in the same memory space in LC3

Tags: assembly, lc3

I need to be able to take two user inputs and store them in the same memory location in LC3 assembly. For example, if the user types in GO- I need to store the G in one register and the O in a second register but combine them together in the same memory location. Essentially, the opposite of the PUTSP function. I don't understand how you can put one in bits 0-8 and specify that the other goes into bits 9-15 so it the PUTSP function is run they are printed out as GO.

Comment: Use shift and bitwise OR?

Answer (score 0):

so essentially the pseudocode will look something like

```
doublechr = 0
r0 = getc();
doublechr += r0
doublechr = doublechr << 8;
r0 = getc();
doublechr += r0;
```

Remember that a left shift is equivalent to multiplying by a power of two.  You only need to simply perform successive adds to double the register which contains "doublechr".

A bitwise or is not needed since the bottom 8 bits are guaranteed to be zero after shifting a simple ADD instruction is all that's needed.